# How to access a JavaScript property with a similar namespace as my TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript

In my page's JavaScript, there's some server-generated code to set up API URLs:

```
Module.Web.Page = { CoreApiUrl: "http://server/apiCore/" };
```

I've created a class to display state machines in TypeScript, and I'm using the same namespace that the rest of my team is using. As a side note, this code is going to be called from both TypeScript and JavaScript code elsewhere.

```
module Module.Web {
    export class StateMachine {
        private stateMachineUrl: string;
        constructor() {
            this.stateMachineUrl = Module.Web.Page.CoreApiUrl + "loadstatemachine"
        }
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler doesn't like it, though: `Property 'Page' does not exist on type 'typeof Web'.` I've tried declaring the interface, but that doesn't fix the compiler error.

```
declare module Module.Web {
    interface Page {
        CoreApiUrl : string;
    }
}
```

I've tried putting the interface declaration adjacent to the StateMachine class definition, but that doesn't fix it either:

```
module Module.Web {
    interface Page {
        CoreApiUrl : string;
    }
    export class StateMachine {
        // same as before
    }
}
```

How can I get the TypeScript compiler to <del>kneel before Zod</del> accept the existence of Module.Web.Page.CoreApiUrl without complaining? It looks like the main problem is that both the JavaScript property and the TypeScript class are different properties of the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> accept the existence of Module.Web.Page.CoreApiUrl without complaining

Your attempt:

```
declare module Module.Web {
    interface Page {
        CoreApiUrl : string;
    }
}
```

Would only work if *the variable* `Module.Web.Page` was *of type* `Module.Web.Page`. This is probably not the case, and you need to declare the variable + type:

```
declare module Module.Web {
    interface PageType {
        CoreApiUrl : string;
    }
    export var Page:PageType;
}
```